# postgres query on double precision column not returning correct results

Tags: postgresql, double-precision

I have a double precision column in my database called "position."

If I have a row with a value in that column that is: `0.564593301435407`

And I have a query that has a WHERE statement like the following:

```
WHERE "position" >= 0.564593301435407
```

(i.e., Querying for greater than or equal to that exact same value)

It does NOT return that column.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your exact problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4cb15/6

However, at 15 significant figures you're very close to the limit of accuracy on double precisions,  and the fiddle suggests that the value might be getting rounded to 0.56459330143541 where a numeric would not be.

I'd suggest that if high precision comparisons are a priority for you then [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) is a better choice of data type.

Comment: Oh, you wrote the same already. So I deleted my dupe. +1 and I took the liberty and added a link to the manual.

Comment: Yes, this is a floating point accuracy problem. If I round the numbers to 4-5 decimal places, will this solve most of the issues with the precision comparisons, or do I still run the risk of problems because it's still being stored as a floating point?

Comment: One of the problems here is that floating point numbers are not suitable for accurate storage of arbitrary decimals. Interesting reading - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT -- Personally, I've got no use for them. I'm more interested in accuracy of storage and comparison for decimal numbers than whatever advantages floating points may have.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're suffering from [Floating Point Accuracy Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Specifically, it is a code smell to compare floating-point values for equality because of the rounding errors when converting between binary and decimal.